# Customize Submenus to change background color and don't close [SherlockActionBar]

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, customization, background-color

I'm new using the ActionBar and SherlockActionBar.

What I'm trying to do is to add a "Menu" to the ActionBar(AB), and when the submenu item is clicked change his background color, and don't close the menu.

the reason is beacuse i'll try to do some type of "filter"

I add the code, where Is supposed to change the background color, but I don't know how to do it.

The option of don't close the menu when the item is clicked I don't know if its possible, cause I never seen it.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    ActionBar actionBar;
    boolean boolSubitem1;
    boolean boolSubitem2;
    boolean boolSubitem3;
    boolean boolSubitem4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolSubitem1 = false;
        boolSubitem2 = false;
        boolSubitem3 = false;
        boolSubitem4 = false;

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Testing");
        actionBar.setSubtitle("Miau");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.item1:
            return true;
        case R.id.subitem1:
            if(boolSubitem1) {
                //CHANGE BACKGROUNDCOLOR
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.subitem2:
            if(boolSubitem2) {
                //CHANGE BACKGROUNDCOLOR
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.subitem3:
            if(boolSubitem3) {
                //CHANGE BACKGROUNDCOLOR
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.subitem4:
            if(boolSubitem4) {
                //CHANGE BACKGROUNDCOLOR
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

And the XML file of the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="Test1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem1"
                android:title="SubMenu1"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem2"
                android:title="SubMenu2"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem3"
                android:title="SubMenu3"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subitem4"
                android:title="SubMenu4"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem which is a bit like yours, because I wanted to change overflow menu text color & background colour.

I just override `onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet args)` in my `MainActivity.java` and verify if the `View` which is created is from class `android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView`.

Then, I just find `TextView` inside and changes its text color (see below for the code)

Code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
    // Do you own inflater stuff here 
    // Check for menu items (Options menu AKA menu key) 
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView")) {
        try { 
            // Ask our inflater to create the view 
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).createView(name, null, attrs); 
            // Kind of apply our own background 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!Common.compatible(Common.color, 0xFF000000)) {
                        try {
                            ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((ListMenuItemView)view).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((ListMenuItemView)view).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                        }
                   }
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Common.color);
                }
            });
            return view;
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Source :  [Change custom SubMenu background color with Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041524/change-custom-submenu-background-color-with-java-code/39050862#39050862)

Comment: OK, I will remember next time.