# Change custom SubMenu background color with Java code

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-menu

In my home activity, I have a toolbar with a custom ***Overflow menu*** and I want it to change color to be accorded with toolbar background color (cause toolbar background color can change (user changes to his own favorite color))...I don't know how to do it :

Here's my `overflow_menu.xml` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/overflow_save_current" app:showAsAction="always" android:title="@string/overflow_save_current" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save_light" />
<item android:id="@+id/overflow_settings" app:showAsAction="always" android:title="@string/overflow_settings" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings_light" />
<item android:id="@+id/overflow_overflow" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow_light">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/overflow_feed_back" app:showAsAction="never|withText" android:title="@string/overflow_feed_back" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_send_now_light" />
        <item android:id="@+id/overflow_about_us" app:showAsAction="never|withText" android:title="@string/overflow_about_us" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about_light" />
        <item android:id="@+id/overflow_exit" app:showAsAction="never|withText" android:title="@string/overflow_exit" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_forward_light" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

And here's `OnPrepareOptionsMenu()` method :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* Resources res = getResources();
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_feed_back);
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("* " + res.getString(R.string.overflow_feed_back));
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    item.setTitle(builder); */
    if (!Common.compatible(Common.color, 0xFF000000)) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_save_current).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_save_dark);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_settings).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings_dark);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_overflow).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow_dark);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_save_current).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_save_light);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_settings).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings_light);
        menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_overflow).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow_light);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I've already tried to change background color of each element...but I got NPE each time, with `menu.findItem(R.id.overflow_about_us).getActionView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`

Hope you'll find a solution for me, Darkball60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...no one helped me...so I had to work alone...hours and hours...to finally find the solution :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
    // Do you own inflater stuff here 
    // Check for menu items (Options menu AKA menu key) 
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView")) {
        try { 
            // Ask our inflater to create the view 
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).createView(name, null, attrs); 
            // Kind of apply our own background 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!Common.compatible(Common.color, 0xFF000000)) {
                        try {
                            ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((ListMenuItemView)view).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((ListMenuItemView)view).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0xFF000000);
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                        }
                    }
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Common.color);
                }
            });
            return view;
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

If background is dark...so textColor is white...and if background is light, textColor is black.

Below are two screens with different toolbar color : [image: Red toolbar] [image: Green toolbar]

Hope it helps someone else than me, Darkball60 (and if you like the answer...feel free to upvote :))

Comment: No problem. Actually it was pretty hard to figure out how to do that directly in Java to be able to change it dynamically